# A single user credential to connect to multiple tenants

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate for its multi-tenancy support. When a user log in, I would like to present to the user the list of tenants it has access to. For instance, if a user with email admin@example.com is part of Tenant-A and Tenant-B, would like to offer the choice to switch between tenants.

This does not seem to be easily doable. Each user can be mapped to a single Tenant (AbpUsers table).

What would be the best way to allow a user to access multiple tenants? The only way I think this can be done is by adding a N:M table between User and Tenant, but then will ABP allow me to do context switching between tenants?

Answer (score 2):

By design, tenant data (including users, roles...) are completely isolated from each other and can not be shared easily.

We solved this issue with "Account linking" feature in AspNet Zero. With this feature, you can connect your accounts in different tenants and then switch between accounts with a single click. It basically maps those accounts (users) in database and logs out & logs in automatically when you want to switch. See more info: https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Development-Guide-Core#user-menu

Comment: Did you consider regenerating the JWT token when the switch happens in between those accounts rather than the logout and login process?